# What does "have" in "Jack Chambers, If I could have you up here for a minute" when a host in a party invited a person to give a word?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I watched this film "**Don't worry, Darling**" and there is a scene. In that scene, at a party, a host wanted a man named Jack Chambers to come up on stage and give a word, so he said "**Jack Chambers, If I could have you up here for a minute. Come on, everybody, give him a round of applause**".

What does the verb "**have**" mean in that sentence?

Does it mean **invite** or **welcome**?

Why not "**I would like to invite Jack Chambers to come up here for a minute**" or "**I would like to welcome Jack Chambers for a minute**"?

Comment: It's a mistake, either from the actor or whoever transcribed it. It should say, "*...if I could have **you** up here...*"

Comment: @gotube, I am so sorry. That was my typo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it means something like "invite" or "welcome". [From M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have), the most appropriate definition is probably:

> b: to cause to be in a certain place or state
> *has* people around at all times

Note that the clause does not use standard syntax. As mentioned in a commment above, the speaker may have meant:

> Jack Chambers, if I could have **you** up here for a minute.

This is a sentence fragment but is a common polite way of making a request. Your two suggestions would be fine, as well.